# Why didn't the Omnius wipe out free humans before Tio Holtzman and Sorceresses of Rossak developed the means to defend/attack?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert, brian-herbert

Was there an explicit in-Universe explanation for why Omnius never bothered to physically destroy humans before Tio Holtzman and Sorceresses of Rossak developed the means to defend/attack?

It seems that prior to the events in *The Butlerian Jihad*, humans would have been very easy to destroy given the full resources of the machines and cymeks (or even just the machines).

Comment: Please take the frank-herbert tag off this question. The Dune prequels have absolutely nothing to do with Frank, who would probably be spinning in his grave.

Comment: @Daniel The prequels are based off Frank's notes; I'm sure something this major would have been covered.

Comment: @CajunLuke no, they're not. The only thing KJA+BH *claim* is that the "seventh" Dune book is based on FH's notes. There's no claim that the prequels are, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Omnius suffers 2 fatal flaws

1. Overconfidence, bordering on megalomania
2. a pathological desire to not waste anything

He keeps subjugated humans because they are useful in small ways, if only for amusement value. His own sick and twisted enjoyment is not unique amongst the AI's; Erasmus also finds torturing humans to be fun, and the implication is that other AIs do so as well.

He fails to see the threat of their creativity until it's too late due to his own overconfidence blinding him to the threat.

There is also a potential third fatal flaw: failure to report. The AI's are, as portrayed, the mirror mental image of mankind's worst individuals... As we see with Erasmus, they don't report every detail, and some even do partial self-wipes to prevent being reabsorbed by Omnius. In short, they suffer the same kinds of flaws as humans. This includes not reporting failures, misrepresenting failures' causes, blaming others for failures, and other forms of misrepresentation.

This means it is quite possible that the real threat wasn't reported out of fear of Omnius. At least not until it was too late.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC, Omnius did not believe in wasting anything.  That is why humans were not exterminated and were used as slaves on the synchronized worlds.  So by the same token Omnius must have been looking to conquer the free human worlds, rather than exterminate their population.

Comment: Yeah, but the risk/reward calculation seems kinda wrong here...

Comment: You can just as easily turn this around: before the Holtzman shields the free humans posed no real threat to Omnius. Wiping them out would have been a waste of resources.

Comment: @Dima - Omnius should have been able to factor in the human inventiveness as far as new science/technology. Its mechanism may have been opaque to the machines, but the results shouldn't have been given available historical data.

Comment: @DVK - I agree.  This is one of the big problems I had with just about every Brian Herbert/Kevin Anderson book I've read.  The authors (Anderson in particular, since you can see it through his Seven Suns series, as well) are quick to "fudge" logical decisions in favor of maintaining storyline.

Comment: @Beofett - Hmmm... I kinda enjoyed Seven Suns but read it in small chunks so didn't really concentrate. I might post this as a Q :)

Comment: @DVK - I love the world and the cultures (both alien and human) in Seven Suns, but I find the characters a little inconsistent (some I love, some I find boring, and some I find to act erratically), and I have trouble with the way he rehashes past events over and over.  Although if you read it in small chunks, the rehashing would probably be more helpful than annoying.  I made it about halfway through, then took a break for some other books.